# How to chcek if a variable is "False" in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-templates, boolean

How do I check if a variable is **False** using Django template syntax?

```
{% if myvar == False %}
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Note that I very specifically want to check if it has the Python value `False`. This variable could be an empty array too, which is *not* what I want to check for.

Comment: Having a variable in the template context that can be both a list as well as a boolean seems like the wrong approach in the first place?

Comment: @Risadinha I don't remember my use case. You could be right.

Comment: `{% if not myvar%}` it works in Django 1.11 for sure, I am not how far back you can go, though!

Comment: @Ibo Pretty sure `not myvar` checks if myvar is falsey, not `False`. [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229327/django-templates-if-false?noredirect=1#comment10180045_8269420)

Comment: @mpen so if `myvar` was a boolean,  `not myvar` will return `True` if it was sent to the template as a context variable by the render function regardless of its value (true or false)? in this case, one should check 2 things: 1-`myvar` was provided to the render function, 2-what value `myvar` has if provided. This will be pretty much complicated if `myvar` is  more of a class instace, dictionary, object etc rather than a classic variable.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Django 1.10 [(release notes)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#templates) added the `is` and `is not` comparison operators to the `if` tag. This change makes identity testing in a template pretty straightforward.

```
In[2]: from django.template import Context, Template

In[3]: context = Context({"somevar": False, "zero": 0})

In[4]: compare_false = Template("{% if somevar is False %}is false{% endif %}")
In[5]: compare_false.render(context)
Out[5]: u'is false'

In[6]: compare_zero = Template("{% if zero is not False %}not false{% endif %}")
In[7]: compare_zero.render(context)
Out[7]: u'not false'
```

If You are using an older Django then as of version 1.5 [(release notes)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.5/#minor-features) the template engine interprets `True`, `False` and `None` as the corresponding Python objects.

```
In[2]: from django.template import Context, Template

In[3]: context = Context({"is_true": True, "is_false": False, 
                          "is_none": None, "zero": 0})

In[4]: compare_true = Template("{% if is_true == True %}true{% endif %}")
In[5]: compare_true.render(context)
Out[5]: u'true'

In[6]: compare_false = Template("{% if is_false == False %}false{% endif %}")
In[7]: compare_false.render(context)
Out[7]: u'false'

In[8]: compare_none = Template("{% if is_none == None %}none{% endif %}")
In[9]: compare_none.render(context)
Out[9]: u'none'
```

Although it does not work the way one might expect.

```
In[10]: compare_zero = Template("{% if zero == False %}0 == False{% endif %}")
In[11]: compare_zero.render(context)
Out[11]: u'0 == False'
```

Comment: Will accept this so that it moves to the top and other people using current versions can find it :-)

Comment: I run in a problem when my context variable contains the integer 0 (zero). When it is rendered by django it is interpreted as 'False'. So it looks like i still need a custom template tag like Gabriel Hurley suggested.

Comment: Or You can explicitly check if variable is 0, but maybe template tag is less verbose.

Answer (score 51):

For posterity, I have a few `NullBooleanField`s and here's what I do:

To check if it's `True`:

```
{% if variable %}True{% endif %}
```

To check if it's `False` (note this works because there's only 3 values -- True/False/None):

```
{% if variable != None %}False{% endif %}
```

To check if it's `None`:

```
{% if variable == None %}None{% endif %}
```

I'm not sure why, but I can't do `variable == False`, but I can do `variable == None`.

Comment: A nicer idiom ([recommended by PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), *comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators*) to check for `None`s is using `is`, as None is a singleton

Comment: @Beau: Django templates aren't Python code.  These is no "is" operator in the template conditional expression.

Comment: This should be in a book somewhere. A lot of people use the `models.NullBooleanField()`

Answer (score 44):

I think this will work for you:

```
{% if not myvar %}
```

Comment: The question specifically mentioned checking for `False` values only and should *not* be triggered by empty arrays. This applies to both.

Answer (score 23):

You could write a custom template filter to do this in a half-dozen lines of code:

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter
def is_false(arg): 
    return arg is False
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if myvar|is_false %}...{% endif %}
```

Of course, you could make that template tag much more generic... but this suits your needs specifically ;-)

Comment: Didn't know you could use filters in `ifs`. Cool :) I actually side-stepped the issue by using "None" as my false value instead..but good to know for future reference.

Comment: I try to learn something new every day... glad I could share ;-)

Answer (score 10):

## In old version you can only use the **ifequal** or **ifnotequal**

```
{% ifequal YourVariable ExpectValue %}
    # Do something here.
{% endifequal %}
```

### Example:

```
{% ifequal userid 1 %}
  Hello No.1
{% endifequal %}

{% ifnotequal username 'django' %}
  You are not django!
{% else %}
  Hi django!
{% endifnotequal %}
```

As in the if tag, an {% else %} clause is optional.

The arguments can be hard-coded strings, so the following is valid:

{% ifequal user.username "adrian" %}
    ...
{% endifequal %}
An alternative to the ifequal tag is to use the if tag and the == operator.

ifnotequal
Just like ifequal, except it tests that the two arguments are not equal.

An alternative to the ifnotequal tag is to use the if tag and the != operator.

## However, now we can use if/else easily

```
{% if somevar >= 1 %}
{% endif %}

{% if "bc" in "abcdef" %}
  This appears since "bc" is a substring of "abcdef"
{% endif %}
```

### Complex expressions

All of the above can be combined to form complex expressions. For such expressions, it can be important to know how the operators are grouped when the expression is evaluated - that is, the precedence rules. The precedence of the operators, from lowest to highest, is as follows:

- or
- and
- not
- in
- ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=

## More detail

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: I don't see any mention of checking for False. Is `False` a supported keyword now?

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into this again (certain I had before and came up with a less-than-satisfying solution).

For a tri-state boolean semantic (for example, using `models.NullBooleanField`), this works well:

```
{% if test.passed|lower == 'false' %} ... {% endif %}
```

Or if you prefer getting excited over the whole thing...

```
{% if test.passed|upper == 'FALSE' %} ... {% endif %}
```

Either way, this handles the special condition where you don't care about the `None` (evaluating to False in the if block) or `True` case.

Answer (score 4):

I have had this issue before, which I solved by nested if statements first checking for none type separately.

```
{% if object.some_bool == None %}Empty
{% else %}{% if not object.some_bool %}False{% else %}True{% endif %}{% endif %}
```

If you only want to test if its false, then just

```
{% if some_bool == None %}{% else %}{% if not some_bool %}False{% endif %}{% endif %}
```

EDIT: This seems to work.

```
{% if 0 == a|length %}Zero-length array{% else %}{% if a == None %}None type{% else %}{% if not a %}False type{% else %}True-type {% endif %}{% endif %}{% endif %}
```

Now zero-length arrays are recognized as such; None types as None types; falses as False; Trues as trues; strings/arrays above length 0 as true.

You could also include in the Context a variable false_list = [False,] and then do

```
{% if some_bool in false_list %}False {% endif %}
```

Comment: This differentiates between `None` and `False` but not `[]` which is also false.

Comment: Well I was dealing with a rendering a variable that was always NullBooleanField, (None/True/False).  I believe you could extend it in the same fashion; e.g., {% if some_bool == [] %}{% else %} ... though at this point its starting to look very ugly and may be worthwhile to just to write your own template tag.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Does it even recognize `[]`? It doesn't recognize `False`. Pretty sad that I'd have to write my own template tag for this :\

Comment: @Mark see edit above; you can do {% if 0 == a|length %} instead of {% if some_bool == [] %}.  Actually tested and it works as expected.

Comment: Nice edit... that's certainly one way of doing it. Looks pretty nasty though :) I think a new template tag would be the lesser of evils.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [yesno](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) helper

Eg:

```
{{ myValue|yesno:"itwasTrue,itWasFalse,itWasNone" }}
```

Comment: Nope. Pretty sure I wanted to put a whole block in there, not just a simple string.

Answer (score 3):

I've just come up with the following which is looking good in Django 1.8

Try this instead of value is not False:

```
if value|stringformat:'r' != 'False'
```

Try this instead of value is True:

```
if value|stringformat:'r' == 'True'
```

unless you've been really messing with **repr** methods to make value look like a boolean I reckon this should give you a firm enough assurance that value is True or False.

Answer (score 2):

This is far easier to check in Python (i.e. your view code) than in the template, because the Python code is simply:

```
myvar is False
```

Illustrating:

```
>>> False is False
True
>>> None is False
False
>>> [] is False
False
```

The problem at the template level is that the template `if` doesn't parse `is` (though it does parse `in`).  Also, if you don't mind it, you could try to patch support for `is` into the template engine; base it on the code for `==`.

Comment: But `== False` should work just as well. We don't need `is`, we just need it to recognize `False` as a keyword. I guess it would be easiest to this in the view as you suggested, but... it's annoying having all this one-off booleans cluttering up the place.

Comment: `myvar is False` is against PEP-8; the proper way is `not myvar`

Comment: But doesn't == work in the same manner as is in this case?
>>> False == False #(True)
>>> None == False #(False)
>>> [] == False #(False)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: But it *isn't* necessarily a boolean value. It's a boolean *or* a list. So it's necessary to differentiate.

Comment: `0 is False` is False, `0 == False` is True - so as soon as you don't know your var is a bool, `is` is (no pun intended) probably not what you want.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Mark specifically said, "Note that I **very specifically** want check if **it has the Python value False**. This variable **could be an empty array** too, which is **not what I want to check for**."  Which leads to my illustration above, which leads to `is` being the simplest solution that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the int value of true and false

True = any int
False = zero
so, if we take an example:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated == 1 %}
do something
{% endif %}
```

this mean in python

```
if user.is_authenticated:
    #do something
```

and

```
{% if user.is_authenticated == 0 %}
do something
{% endif %}
```

this mean in python

```
if not user.is_authenticated :
    #do something
```

OR equal

```
if !(user.is_authenticated) :
    #do something
```

OR equal

```
if user.is_authenticated == False :
    #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done:if you use "select" tag.

```
{% if service.active == 0  %} selected {% endif%}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `if not` to check if a variable is `False` in Django Template. *`False` is made by `None`, 0, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)` and so on in Django Template same as Python and [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if) explains more about `if` statement in Django Template:

```
{% if not myvar %}
```