# Django custom template tag which accepts a boolean parameter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/e72cd474c819d15a) on the django-developers list, I can't pass the constant `False` as a parameter to a Django template tag because it will be treated as a variable name not a builtin constant.

But if I want to create a template tag takes needs a true/false parameter, what's the the recommended way to create (in Python) and invoke (in a template) that template tag?

I could simply pass 1 or 0 inside the template and it would work OK, but given that Django template authoring shouldn't require computer programming knowledge (e.g. 1==True, 0==False) of template writers, I was wondering if there is a more appropriate way to handle this case.

Example of tag definition and usage:

```
@register.simple_tag
def some_tag(some_string, some_boolean = True):
    if some_boolean:
        return some_html()
    else
        return some_other_html()

<!-- Error!  False treated as variable name in Request Context -->
{% some_tag "foobar" False %}

<!-- Works OK, but is there a better option? -->
{% some_tag "foobar" 0 %}
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229327

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I came up against this problem a while ago, and arrived at the conclusion that using 1 and 0 was the simplest solution.

However an idea might be to add a context processor which adds `True` and `False` to the template context using respective names:

```
# projectname/appname/context_processors.py

def booleans():
    return {
        'True': True,
        'False': False,
    }
```

Then obviously you would need to add that context processor in your Django settings file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += {
    'projectname.appname.context_processors.booleans',
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's cool. Wish someone suggested that to my question :P

Comment: I'll probably stick with 1 and 0 too, but knowing about the context processor solution will be helpful in the future. thanks!