# django template strange behaviour

Tags: django, django-templates

```
{% if None == False %}
    abc
{% endif %}
```

The above code, strangely my template displayed `abc`. Any explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jason Culverhouse provided the answer in another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667878/django-template-if-condition) i asked.

False and None are treat as variables, instead of constants. If the variables ore not found in the context dictionary, there are resolved to None.

Answer (score 3):

Bizarre.  In regular python,

```
if None == False:
    # this will not run
    print "abc"
```

File a bug on Django.  :)

Comment: Trying filing a ticket but got the following error : Submission rejected as potential spam (BlogSpam says content is spam (badip:state/blacklist.d/127.0.0.1))

Answer (score 1):

This is just the way Python resolves 'truth' for comparison between different types.

See the docs. "None" is considered False.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

**Edit: as below, the python console does not confirm this behaviour, so, I am also surprised. -1 to me!**

Comment: if None == False doesn't yield in my python console.

Comment: Hang on, I just tried it, and my console returned "False". I concede defeat!

Answer (score 0):

For now It seem like you will have to create your own template filter as was suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229327/django-templates-if-false)

Comment: i guess i'll just do it in my logic view side.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do `if not None`.